# Golfing a script that extract citations from a LaTeX document

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I was trying to extract all the citations from a LaTeX file, that is, being able to extract everything in between the two curly braces following \cite (ie, `\cite{bla,blo}` would give me `bla` and `blo`). There are a few corner cases: `\cite{}` may contain one or more citations separated by comma (and there is no comma if there is only one citation) and the `\cite{}` command may span over multiple lines.

So far, I came up with the following one liner which works well:

```
<file.tex grep -oPz "(?s)(?<=\\\\cite{).[^}]*?(?=})" | tr '\n\0,' ' \n\n' | tr -d '[:blank:]' | sort | uniq
```

However, I was wondering whether it would be possible to do it only with one tool, be it sed, grep or awk. I think it would be easier to do it in awk (because the sort | uniq part can easily be done in awk but I was stuck on the extracting part).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is a test case:

```
Aenean consequat \cite{acitation} auctor varius. Pellentesque varius,
 sapien quis faucibus rhoncus, nunc nisl sagittis erat, ac varius magna
 quam eu est. Pellentesque \cite{a citation with spaces is considered
 valid yes but does not produce the correct output but it is not a problem
 because those are not valid in LaTeX} congue maximus efficitur. Quisque
 ac aliquam nisi. Nullam sit
 amet auctor metus, nec varius ipsum. Proin vel lacus sed nisl auctor
 porttitor. Sed id turpis pretium, rhoncus nisi eu, dictum ipsum. Nulla
 facilisi. Vestibulum sed congue \cite{some.citation.here, anotherone} 
metus, vitae \cite{onecitation,
thenexthere} scelerisque sem.Vestibulum eget gravida ante. Suspendisse 
consequat libero eget mauris cursus, sed blandit est euismod. Pellentesque
 porta vitae dolor blandit lacinia. Nulla sit amet rutrum velit, in mollis
 sem. Nunc gravida consectetur \cite{acitation} feugiat.
```

and the output

```
acitation
acitationwithspacesisconsideredvalidyesbutdoesnotproducethecorrectoutputbutitisnotaproblembecausethosearenotvalidinLaTeX
anotherone
onecitation
some.citation.here
thenexthere
```

The order of the output does not matter as long as each citation is only listed once. The result for

```
\cite{a citation with spaces is considered
 valid yes but does not produce the correct output but it is not a problem
 because those are not valid in LaTeX}
```

is undefined behavior since it should not appear in a valid LaTeX document.

Comment: Not much clear, could you please post samples of input and expected output in code tags in your post and let us know the.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I added a test case with the expected output, is it clear enough or should I explain more/add more test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(since I am on mobile couldn't test it, should work but).

`awk -v RS=""   '{while(match($0,/\\cite{[^}]*/)){val=substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6);array[val]++;$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}  END{for(i in array){if(array[i]==1){gsub(/,/,ORS,i);print i}}}'  Input_File`

### Edit:

```
BEGIN {
  RS=""
}

{
  gsub(/ *, */, ",", $0);
  gsub(/ |\n/, "", $0);
  while (match($0,/\\cite{[^}]*/)) {
    val = substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-6);
    split(val, array, ",");
    for (x in array)
      citations[array[x]]++
    $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  }
}

END {
  for(i in citations)
      print i
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Writing awk on mobile is even more impressive. It gives me some more ideas on how to extract the text. However, you don't handle correctly the commas.https://imgur.com/a/R6NXqAI

Comment: You want to simply remove commas right? If yes then let me fix it now.

Comment: Yes, and if two citations are separated by a comma they should appear on two different lines. Basically commas are turned into newlines.

Comment: Could you please try my edited command now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: It almost works. It adds some extra newlines and some extra spaces, and there are some problems with how you handle uniqueness. I was thinking of storing each citations inside a map and print only those which appears once.

Comment: Ok, I have changed code to print only those cites which are coming only once, let me know now?

Comment: Now, it prints only newlines, that is blank output with newlines (the number of newlines is not equal to the number of (unique) citations).

Comment: If I replace `print array[I]` by `print i` I get the citations but again commas are not treated, If I replace `print array[I]` by `print array[i]` I get `1`s which is normal.

Comment: Sure, edited now.kindly do check my edited code and lemme know then. Cheers.

Comment: I apologies got distracted by someone, now code should work I believe.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I can get to the solution I want from now. I'll accept your answer and will add as an edit the solution I'll get in my original post. It's already pretty good I just need to remove unwanted spaces. Something like a `gsub(/ */,,val)` should do it. I'll check the syntax.

Comment: I updated my question with the script which does what I want. Thank you for your help!

Comment: IMHO, you could leave question as it is(may be if possible make it more clear) and UPDATE my answer with adding a heading EDIT where you post your code, you could keep my code too for future reference of people. I really appreciate your intent of keeping thread updated, keep it up buddy. Edit my answer and lemme know then, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\n/bb;/\\cite{/!b;s//\n/;s/.*\n/\n/;:a;/}/!{N;s/\n//2;ba};s//\n/;D;:b;s/^\([^\n]*\),\s*/\1\n/;P;D' file
```

This sed script uses the fact that the `D` command deletes upto and including, the first `\n` in the pattern space (if there is one) and then presents the remains of the pattern space to the sed cycle. If the pattern space is empty it behaves in the same fashion as the `d` command and fetches the next line (minus its newline) into the pattern space and starts the sed cycle as is usual.

The script is in two pieces: if the pattern space contains a newline (only possible if it has already been processed and a newline introduced) it is passed to the `:b` goto marker, otherwise the pattern space is treated in the following way.

If the pattern space does not contain `\\cite{` it is deleted and the sed cycle repeated. Otherwise the pattern space is shortened upto the beginning of the citation and a newline inserted. The end of the citation marked by the closing `}` is also replaced by a newline (a loop is used in the case that the citation flows over one or more lines) and then the `D` command is used to dispatch the sed to go again.

On its return, having deleted the first introduced newline, the citation is now at the start of the pattern space. Separate citations are printed by replacing `,`'s before the second introduced newline by a newline and the sed cycle repeats until the closing of the citation is reached. Then the remainder of the pattern is repeatedly processed until it is empty or does not contain any further citations.